# How to send text file from server to client using C programming

Tags: c, sockets, file-transfer

I am trying to send a text file from a server to a client, but am not sure on how to proceed with coding this.

I have been reading some tutorials and managed to receive data from a client, then send a confirmation back to the client saying that the data had been received. But I would like to modify this so that I am sending an entire text file over to a client.

I am a total newbie to C and TCP socket programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

My code for the server so far:

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Create a TCP socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    // Assign a name/port number to socket
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
    // Establish a queue for connections
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof (cli_addr);
    // Extract a connection from the queue
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
            (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
            &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    // Read/write
    n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
    n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try taking a working sample code (plenty of it can be found in Internet) and modify for your needs?

Comment: what OS is the server? client?

Answer (score 1):

Use a

```
while ((nread = read(filefd, filebuf, sizeof(filebuf))) > 0) {
     size_t toread = nread, off = 0, wr;
     while (toread > 0) {
         wr = write(connfd, filebuf + off, toread);
         if (wr >= 0) {
             toread -= wr;
             off += wr;
         } else {
             /* handle a write error */
         }
    }
}
```

loop.

Comment: will not work if write() doesn't send all data (which can happen if the send buffer is filled with data).

Comment: Return value checking part has been bolded. Of course, the loop continues until the nread total equals the nwritten total.

Comment: checking for return value of write() call would make the code much more complicated. I understand that in your implementation you are having more complex construct, but that one should be provided in the answer imho, cause the simplified version is just not correct.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, from where the file is to be send use

k=sendfile(sock_desc2,filehandle,NULL,obj.st_size);

On the client side receive it with read and write commands as in the below code

I had a similar assignment recently.Check out the code.
Hope it is working!
http://pastebin.com/Nep9ws9T

Comment: will not work if write() doesn't send all data (which can happen if the send buffer is filled with data).

Comment: Write() is not sending the data, right? It writes the data received from filefd through filebuf to the target file connfd.

Comment: Anyway in my program I used a different approach, First send the size of the file via TCP to the receiver and read exactly that number of blocks with read command on the receiving side.Its there in the code I shared

Comment: @Arun i think what you mean is that the write in your while loop, writes to a file, not to the socket. The sendfile writes to the socket. It is a bit confusing since you use 'connfd' as handle for write.

Comment: @AndersK. As write() can be used to write to socket, my comment applies. Arun confused himself, as it seems - write in his code clearly writes to socket (aka sends the data).

Comment: @Arun if connfd is a socket descriptor, then write writes the data to socket outbound buffer. But this buffer is small and can be filled up easily, so write() can write less than asked. Read the docs.

Comment: Please ignore the code I had posted in the above answer.I actually copied the answer of @moshbear.
In my pastebin code, in the SENDER side file is send by sendfile().
On the receiver side, the file is first written to a array and then from the array to the file descriptor. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe UDP will be concise.

```
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes, int flags, const struct sockaddr * destaddr, socklen_t desteln);
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

doesn't this work?
`send(new_fd, buf, bufsize, 0)`

Comment: No. UDP requires SOCK_DGRAM, whereas the post uses SOCK_STREAM, which is TCP.

Comment: If get the `newfd` , we can just use `send` function, as we have get a connection.